# Which ionic channels of Pacemakers can work in very low frequencies in extrasystole?

Tags: physiology, cardiology, electrocardiography, pathophysiology

At frequency 0-3 Hz.
Like computer processors which can work at low frequencies and controlling under- and overvoltage.

Normal most significant channels are Ca2+ and K+ that are changing.
However, I am not convinced that they can work with such a low frequencies.
There must be some other channels that are triggering the extrasystole on.

**Which ionic channels of Pacemakers can work in 2-3 Hz triggering extrasystole?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think none.
It is so specific frequency range that the possible sources are

- autonomic nervous system and
- some reflex arch.

Also, the frequency is logically low with autonomic triggering.
My conjecture is that sympaticus starts up extrasystoles.
I think it must go through some reflex arch to be so specific.