# Which reflex arcs work in Heart with extrasystoles?

Tags: physiology, cardiology, reflexes, electrocardiography

I am researching what is triggering the extrasystoles - initial idea from [this thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16513/which-ionic-channels-of-pacemakers-can-work-in-very-low-frequencies-in-extrasyst) about *Which ionic channels of Pacemakers can work in very low frequencies in extrasystole?*
I am interested in the reflex arc with extrasystoles.

I am not completely sure if the intrinsic regulation of the heart can start specific stimuli.
I have now intuition that not possible.

**What are the reflex arcs of the heart?**

Comment: Not to be fussy about it, but it will help someone searching for your question.

Comment: Edits are always welcome :)